# Getting a Selected Text In SWT Browser Widgets

Tags: java, browser, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am implementing SWT Browser in my Project for displaying a WebPage.
After displaying a web page into this browser, if a user selects particular text, how can I get the selected text? please help me with suitable example

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this [link](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t69915.html) will help you out.

This link posits the idea of using a StatusTextListener to intercept text selections.  Below is a snippet of the StatusTextListener implementation.

```
// Status Text Listener Interface. 
public void changed (StatusTextEvent evt) { 
    String text = evt.text; 
    if ((text != null) && (text.length() > 0)) { 
        if ((! text.equalsIgnoreCase ("Done")) && (! text.equals (lastStatusText))) { 
            System.err.println (evt.text); 
            lastStatusText = text; 
        } 
    } 
} // End of changed().
```

Comment: Never just post a link. When the link becomes unreachable, your answer will be useless. Post the link and at least a summary.

Comment: I am trying this code. this give only Hyperlink text not getting plain text on mouse selection

Comment: I too tried the code, I am also getting only hyperlinks text. I NEED THIS FOR PLAIN TEXT.

Comment: Added new answer rather than muck up this with a comment.  See the new answer and maybe it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work well for me.  Give it a try.

```
static String SCRIPT01 = "var html = \"\";"+
"if (typeof window.getSelection != \"undefined\") {"+
    "var sel = window.getSelection();"+
    "if (sel.rangeCount) {"+
        "var container = document.createElement(\"div\");"+
        "for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {"+
            "container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());"+
        "}"+
        "html = container.innerHTML;"+
    "}"+
"} else if (typeof document.selection != \"undefined\") {"+
    "if (document.selection.type == \"Text\") {"+
        "html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;"+
    "}" +
"}" +
"return html";

browser.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseUp(MouseEvent arg0) {
        String selection = (String) browser.evaluate(SCRIPT01);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDown(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent arg0) {
        String selection = (String) browser.evaluate(SCRIPT01);
    }
});
```